# "click" vs "click on" vs "click through"

Tags: word-choice, differences, phrasal-verbs

How does "click" in the context of the sentences below differ from click on and click through?

> 1. Click the link to subscribe.
> 2. Click on the link to subscribe.
> 3. Click through the link to subscribe.

Are all the 3 sentences above correct?

Comment: I **clicked** the link **through clicking on** the mouse button for the subscription.

Comment: There's a similar question elsewhere on the site:  https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/53794/when-to-use-click-and-click-on .  As to _click through the link_ , I would interpret this as meaning that the link is the first in a series of links to be clicked through in order to subscribe. It is certainly the most uncommon of the three alternatives for a simple mouse click on the _Subscribe_ button.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my personal take on the three:

"Click the link" seems to me to be normal 21st century usage for people who are familiar with technology, but I suspect that varies from place to place (either physical or digital locations).

"Click on the link" is totally acceptable and to me is merely more evocative of moving a cursor over the link before clicking it. This is probably what I would say to my parents when walking them through doing something on the internet.

"Click through the link" is relatively uncommon, and always seems to imply that the link will take you somewhere else, probably to a different domain. I've mostly seen this in articles that have a link to the source of the thing they are talking about.

Comment: Click through the list of links to see if you can find the right one.